# Common error in BlueJ but it isnt getting solved. Related to Brackets

Tags: java, brackets, bluej

Okay, So the Problem with this is that the brackets are annoying. It never seems to work for some reason. I have checked on other websites but this does not get fixed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class x14
    {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        double b2 = Math.pow(b,2);
        double sq = Math.sqrt(b2 - 4*a*c);
        public void main()
        {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Please input 'a'");
            a = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please input 'b'");
            b = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please input 'c'");
            c = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Thank you!");

            double x1 = 0.0;
            double x2 = 0.0;
            x1=(-b+sq)/2a;// Says "Please place ';' here"
            x2=(-b-sq)/2a;// Says "Please place ';' here"
            /* When I Try this : ((-b+sq)/2a);
             * It says i have to place ')' at the end.
             */


            System.out.println("Equation x1 : " + x1);
            System.out.println("Equation x2 : " + x2);
            if(sq > 0)
            System.out.println("The Roots are Real and unequal");
            else if(sq == 0)
            System.out.println("The Roots are Real and Equal");
            else if(sq < 0)
            System.out.println("The Roots are imaginary");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing multiply operator.

```
x1=(-b+sq)/2a;// Says "Please place ';' here"
x2=(-b-sq)/2a;//
```

should be: (observe the *)

```
  x1=((-b+sq)/(2*a);// Says "Please place ';' here"
  x2=((-b-sq)/(2*a);//
```

Comment: Oh God.. thank you. That has to be the silliest error I have ever made.

Comment: Thanks! That's the cue for me to stop for tonight XD

Comment: @user1817822: Ha ha. By the way don't forget to accept answer if it helped you.

Comment: I think you meant `x1=(-b+sq)/(2*a)`, otherwise you're getting `((-b+sq)/2)*a`, which is NOT what you want.

Comment: @JimGarrison: I don't know what OP wants there, is it (2*a) (or) ../2*a. But the issue was due to no * operator between values. If OP looking for what you commented, I don't have any issues to update.

Comment: It's the quadratic formula, so it must be `(2*a)`.

Comment: @JimGarrison: Ok. Updated. Not an expert in Math. Sorry about that